# Association rule mining on types of customers and their attributes presented in a DataFrame

Tags: python, machine-learning, apriori

I want to find the rules where Users have cancelled hotel bookings. My data Looks like this

```
df.head()
>>

hotel         is_canceled    lead_time  year    month     week
City Hotel    1              171        2016    August    36
Resort Hotel  l              29         2017    June      24
Resort Hotel  l              244        2015    September 36
City Hotel    1              183        2017    May       19
City Hotel    1              86         2016    January   5
```

There are 32 columns/attributes. How am Supposed to apply some Association Rule Mining tool on this data to find on which rules user can cancel a booking?

I can do

```
records = []
for i in range(len(df)):
    records.append([cancel_df.columns[j]+'='+str(cancel_df.values[i,j]) for j in range(0,df.shape[1])])
```

to get Market basket type data which provides me something like

```
records[0]
>>
['hotel=Resort Hotel',
 'is_canceled=1',
 'lead_time=85',
 'year=2015',
 'month=July',
 'week=27',]
```

and can apply (dummy Solution)

```
from apyori import apriori
assosciation_rules=apriori(records,min_support=0.1)
assosciation_results=list(assosciation_rules)
```

With 32 columns, there are numerical columns like `Price` and  mostly Categorical values too. If  I apply Binning or One Hot Encoding, It'll make hundreds of new columns. If I apply some algo, like Apriori, It'll blow the memory.

**Please help with a better approach, algorithm and the package to tackle this kind of problem**

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is not as simple as frequent itemset mining (with apriori as algorithm) because I guess you are interested in combinations of attributes with a high amount of cancelled bookings.
A search term that might help is Subgroup Discovery.
It is a generalization of the frequent itemset mining task to questions like yours.

---

Disclamer: I am part of the development team for pysubgroup

I would suggest using the [pysubgroup](https://github.com/flemmerich/pysubgroup) package for subgroup discovery in python. You should be able to adjust the example from the github page for your scenario. Essentially replace `'Survived'` with `'is_canceled'` and `BeamSearch` with `BestFirstSearch` and you should be good to go. Just make sure you fetch the current version from github rather than pypi ;)